# How could I set window styles depending on current screen?

Tags: wpf, styles, touch

I am developing an app which has a number of windows. Depending on the workstation conifguration there may be one or more screens which may include a small touch screen.

I would like to change some control styles if a window is on a touch screen. This is especially interesting for buttons which may be too small to hit reliably with a finger tip.

Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

you could look into MVVM design pattern. It is designed to separate to presentation of your UI from the data & commands. In MVVM terminology you would have one ViewModel with functions for handling button presses etc and two Views, one for each screen type. A MVVM framework can help you display the correct view on each screen. I have used [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) to achieve similar functionality.

Comment: +1 for Caliburn.Micro. I am actually doing something similar to your suggestion (1 model, 2 views). I guess I could detect which screen the view will display on and then select the appropriate view...